# Whether the resource id in Android xml can be used before being declared

Tags: android, xml

I wonder that Whether the resource id in Android xml can be used before being declared? when I test it in a demo application , compiled in Android Studio and ran in the phone both work. The xml code in demo as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id ="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bt"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" am a button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Activity code as following:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
`setContentView(R.layout.example_layout);`

Comment: great! I make it more complete just now

Comment: If you tried and it works, then I think you're good, right ? If it was my code, I'd have added a plus symbol after the `@` so that the id is added to the R file. I believe this is explicitly required the first time you use an id in a layout but if it's working for you as is, then I'd take that as a win.